# How to get name and other info of saved wifi network above android Q?

Tags: android, android-studio, wifimanager

I want to get the name and network id of saved wifi network.

```
List<WifiConfiguration> wifiConfigurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
```

This works below android Q. But does not give name of network. I want to show name and other info of already saved wifi network in android app

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getConfiguredNetworks()).

[image]

Comment: Can you please help me by writing the code to get info for saved wifi networks

Comment: Sure. Contact me with github

Comment: Sir, please help me here. I don't know much about github. I will be very thankful to you

Comment: go to this link: https://github.com/AntennaPod/AntennaPod/issues/3387#issuecomment-529608249

Comment: Sir I can not get the names of saved networks. WifiConfiguration list is giving other info such as, ip address, newtwork id, but how i will show the names of saved wifi networks?